# Need solution for fetching data from two tables query

Tags: sql

The following are the IPL matches database relations:

1. `Player (playerId, name, playsfor)` : details of each player and the team he plays for. Playsfor references teamid in Team table.
2. `Team (Teamid, Name)` : Team details.
3. `PlayerBat (Playerid, matchid, Runscored, Teamid)` : Runs scored by a player in each match. Has a row for the player only if the player plays in the match.
4. `PlayerBowl (Playerid, matchid, WicketTaken, teamid)` : wickets taken by a player in each match. Has a row for the player only if the player plays in the match.
5. `PlayerMatchDetails (Playerid, Matchid)` : contains the names of the players who have played in the match.

You are required to write an SQL query to get the total number of runs scored by Team id T02 in the match IPL11
Note 1: The column(s) to be displayed in the result or output should be totalRun only.

Can anyone help me on ths, I am new to sql. How do I fetch the data from two or more records?

Comment: Omg!! IPL!! Ohk sorry.. now i'll read the question... But we can't get the total runs just from the batting total of the players... what about the extras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  sum(Runscored) as totalRun 
  from `PlayerBat`
  where  Teamid = 'T02' and matchid = 'IPL11'
```

Comment: y should v give playerbat under quotes?

Comment: This is not quote it is back quote or backtick.
Backticks also allow spaces and other special characters (except for backticks, obviously) in table/column names. They're not strictly necessary but a good idea for safety.

If you follow sensible rules for naming tables and columns backticks should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the total runs only, there is no need for joining the other tables and you can simply do this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Runscored) AS TotalRuns
FROM PlayerBat
WHERE teamid = 'T02'
  AND matchid = 'IPL11';
```

Comment: Grt gamal, thanks for the quick reply, but what about the function of match id here and why is it ipl 11

Comment: @karthick23 Isn't this `IPL11` is the match id? and the `teamid` `'T02'` isn't it the team id or the team name? I assumed that they are the ids if they aren't you should join the other tables.

Comment: @karthick23 - **Note that:** I assumed that the total run is the sum of the values in the column `Runscored`. Is this right? if not how it is calculated?